# Decorated class type

Tags: typescript

A class is decorated to have `foo` static property:

```
interface IFoo {
    foo: boolean;
}

function foo<T>() {
    return (Class: T): T & IFoo => Object.assign(Class, { foo: true });
}

@foo<typeof Bar>()
class Bar { }

const Baz: IFoo = Bar;
console.log(Baz.foo);
```

This causes an error:

> Type 'typeof Bar' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'.

It appears that TypeScript typing system ignores the fact that `Bar` was decorated.

I'm aware that there are certain type problems with decorators. What are the workarounds here?

Comment: TypeScript is structurally typed, that means if you add a static property `foo` to `Bar` it is assignable to a variable of type `IFoo`, no need for a decorator.

Comment: That's correct. The idea was to not do that and use decorators instead (IFoo can be more complex than a single property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript does not allow decorators to modify the structure of the decorated class. You can however use a function taht takes the class and modifies it:

```
interface IFoo {
    foo: boolean;
}

function foo<T extends  new (...  args: any[]) => any>(cls:T) : T & IFoo {
    return Object.assign(cls, { foo: true });
}


const Bar =foo(class  { })

console.log(Bar.foo);
```

Comment: Ironically, this is one of few use cases where decorators are supposed to replace regular wrapper functions. Guess this is all we have for now. A relevant issue, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881